# Eclipse 2018-12 version - SVN option is missing in Import Project menu

Tags: eclipse, svn, import, project, eclipse-2018-12

We are having trouble importing a project from SVN into Eclipse 2018-12 version.
It was working fine until we came up to some random errors.
After a lot of debugging, we decided to install a clean setup of Eclipse 2018-12 on the machine.
However, the issue remains.

Any ideas on what could be the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error and what URL do you enter? Note that there are two different plug-ins for Eclipse that enable Subversion integration - Subclipse and Subversive. Which one do you use?

Comment: Why using such an old Eclipse version? Which plug-in do you use for SVN? What are these random errors and why do you think this is related to Eclipse at all?

Comment: I cannot install any plugin, since I do not have internet access from this server. I have tried the latest version of Eclipse but the result is the same. Moreover, it seems that someone has integrated Eclipse with GitHub. How can I remove this link and use again the Tortoise SVN folder i have created on the server? I managed to disconnect the GitHub repository, still there is no option in Team menu when I right click on the project to synchronize with repository, only Apply Patch or Share Project. Thanks!

Comment: Unshare/disconnect a project and then want to do a synchronize does not make sense. Please answer my questions of my previous comment by editing your question.

Comment: Disconnect from github and connect to Tortoise SVN folder is what I want to do. I tried as previously commented also the latest version, without any luck.